# How to select only Month/Year with the InputDate control

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

The ASP.NET Razor components are nice. It's so easy to get a month/day/year.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="birthdayBox">Birth</label>
    <InputDate id="birthdayBox" class="form-control" @bind-Value="UserInput.BirthDay" />
</div>
```

But does the control support month/year without the day? Thanks.

Comment: `<InputDate` is rendered to `<input type="date"` in html. How the browser then renders this is very much dependent on the browser and version and each one usually does it differently. If you want custom control over how the date (or just month and year) is selected you need to invest time into building (or better yet reusing) a front end date picker control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem. Using directly the HTML `<input type="month"/>` works correctly but when using the Blazor `<InputDate>` I can't only select Month and Year.
I have finally used the HTML with the binding, in your case:

```
<input type="month" id="birthdayBox" class="form-control" @bind="UserInput.BirthDay" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is supported in Blazor (at least it is now, I'm not sure about last year. Here's how to do this, using the `InputDateType` enumeration:

```
<InputDate Type="InputDateType.Month" class="form-control" @bind-Value="SelectedMonth"/>
```